# How do I get string input without using gets() or scanf/sscanf?

Tags: objective-c

How can I get input from the console in Objective C? My concern is to avoid the possibility of buffer overflows, which is why I want to steer clear of `gets()` and `scanf()/sscanf()`. From searching StackOverflow, that's all I've been seeing. Is `scanf()` more secure in Objective C to the extent that I wouldn't have to worry?

Just recently, I found this example: I like it; but is there already a class for such?

`printf("What is your name?");
     NSFileHandle *input = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardInput];
     NSData *inputData = [NSData dataWithData:[input availableData]];
     NSString *inputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:inputData
                                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     inputString = [inputString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                       [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
     printf("Hello %s.n",[inputString UTF8String]);`

Comment: Write an iOS app in Objective-C with a UITextField and take input from that perhaps? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard C I/O functions can be used, as you indicate. They are **not** more secure just because you are using Objective-C. To avoid buffer overflow issues use `fgets` rather and `gets`. Note you will be reading a C-style string and will need to convert it if you need an `NSString`.

At the Cocoa level you can use `NSFileHandle` as you show. Note that `availableData` returns all the available data not the next line, but as the console device is usually set to line mode what will be returned is the next line provided the user has not typed ahead.

At a lower level you can look at `read`.

HTH

Comment: `fgetln()` is also worth a look if you want line-oriented input. If you want to allow the user to edit the line as they type you should look at GNU readline or BSD readline.